# Is a date in Oracle-SQL without a time-value always 00:00:00?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Heyho,

I need to grab some datas from actions which been done from date A 00:00:00 and date B 00:00:00 (in this case
Date A: 16.07.2010
Date B: 20.07.2010)
so i wrote this select-statement:

```
Select avg(cnt),fext from (
        Select 
            to_char(mytable.dateadded, 'DD.MM.YYYY') dateadded,
            fext, 
            count(id) cnt 
        from mytable 
        where dateadded between
            to_date('16.07.2010', 'dd,MM,YYYY') and 
            to_date('20.07.2010', 'dd,MM,YYYY')
        group by 
            to_char(mytable.dateadded, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
            fext)
group by fext;
```

The original (and working) statement had:

```
    to_date('16.07.2010 00:00:00', 'dd,MM,YYYY HH24:Mi:SS') and 
    to_date('20.07.2010 00:00:00', 'dd,MM,YYYY HH24:Mi:SS')
```

so the question is: does the

```
    to_date('16.07.2010', 'dd,MM,YYYY') and 
    to_date('20.07.2010', 'dd,MM,YYYY')
```

already set the time to date A and B to 00:00:00?

Greetz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you does not specify time part of date it will be 00:00:00.

If you worry about time part you always can truncate time part:

```
Trunc(to_date('16.07.2010', 'dd.MM.YYYY')) and 
Trunc(to_date('20.07.2010', 'dd.MM.YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use ANSI date literals, which doesn't allow time to be specified and is thus with a 00:00:00 time part internally:

```
dateadded between date '2010-07-16' and date '2010-07-20'
```

Your expressions look odd, as your date string has dots as the time component separator, but your date format has commas. Oracle accepts it though:

```
rwijk@XE> select to_date('16.07.2010', 'dd,MM,YYYY') from dual;

TO_DATE('16.07.2010
-------------------
16-07-2010 00:00:00

1 row selected.
```

I'd use the ANSI date literal for its simplicity.

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 2):

this query will returns you one row which answers your question i think :

```
SELECT TO_DATE('16.07.2010 00:00:00', 'dd,MM,YYYY HH24:Mi:SS'),  
       TO_DATE('16.07.2010', 'dd,MM,YYYY')
  FROM dual
 WHERE to_date('16.07.2010 00:00:00', 'dd,MM,YYYY HH24:Mi:SS') = to_date('16.07.2010', 'dd,MM,YYYY')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one thing that SQL is consistent about - if you don't provide a time portion on a DATE data type that includes a time portion (IE Oracle, PostgreSQL while MySQL and SQL Server explicitly call it DATETIME), then the time portion is defaulting to exactly midnight of that date - 00:00:00.  And being midnight, that means the start of the date - if you want to include the entire date in a date comparison, the value's time portion needs to be 23:49:49 -- a second to midnight.

Comment: typo: a second to midnight should be 23:59:59, not 49

Answer (score 0):

23:59:59 is a second to midnight. Essentially midnight is defined as the start of a day: 00:00:00. Then the seconds clock up to the end of the day.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This does not answer the question. Since it is an old question and already has an accepted answer with high reputation, new answers are unlikely to provide added value. If you do answer such questions, ensure that you do provide such added value (on topic of the question). As a new user, it may be more rewarding to focus on questions without answers.